# Is it possible to change refresh rate after background location service has already started?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, background-service

I would like to know if I can change refresh rate of background location service in the middle of its work. For example, user sets the refresh rate to 10 seconds and after some time he wants to change that refresh rate.

I wonder if this is possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I am initializing and starting background location service with this:

```
locationService = new LocationService(TimeFrequency, DistanceFrequency);
StartService(new Intent(this, locationService.Class));
```

I know that I can stop current service and then start another with different refresh rate but can I change refresh rate of current service somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, you would just need to "unrequest" updates, then re-request them with the new criteria.